# Extjs - Add warning image in a textfied dynamically when data vaildation fails using extjs

Tags: css, image, textfield, extjs4.2

I am trying to change the background color and add a warning image within the textfield when the data validation fails. So far, I am able to change the background color but unable to insert a image in the textfield on the right side.

I am using Extjs 4.2.1. Here is my code:

Textfield whose background color needs to be changed and embed a warning image within:

```
{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'first',
            id: 'first1',                   
            //allowBlank: false,
            //fieldCls: 'varun',
            //emptyText: 'placeholder text',
            vtype: 'time1',
            inputAttrTpl: " data-qtip='Enter your first name!' ",
},
```

Validator code that is being called:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    //  vtype validation function
    time1: function(val, field) {
            //alert(val);
            //field.setFieldStyle('background-color: white;');
            alert("1");
            //var val = this.findField('first').getValue;
            alert(val);
            alert("2");
            if(val == 'O')  {
                //alert("hell");
                //field.addClass('varun');
                //field.invalidClass('x-form-invalid');
                //field.setFieldStyle('background-color: green;');
                //field.getEl().setStyle('background', 'red');
                //getInputEl().gettyle().addCls('varun');
                alert("1");
                //textfield.removeCls('x-form-display-field');
                //field.getInputEl('first1').addCls('varun');
                //field.getInputEl('first').replaceCls('varun');
                field.getCmp('first').replaceCls('varun');
                //field.inputEl.replaceCls('varun');
                //field.addStyleName('varun');
                //Ext.getCmp('first1').addClass('varun');
                //field.getEl().style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                alert("2");
                //field.setFieldStyle('varun');
                //field.applyStyles('varun');
                return true;
            }
        //return true;  
    },
    // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
    time1Text: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".',
    // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
    time1Mask: /[\d\s:amp]/i
});
```

CSS custom class:

```
.varun {
background:url(warning.gif);
background-size:16px 16px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
background-color:green;
}
```

If I use fieldCls property for default condition it works fine, but I need to change it dynamically. I have tried lots of syntax but none of them working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule is the standard rule for the classic theme:

```
.x-form-type-text textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-text input.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-password textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-password input.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-number textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-number input.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-email textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-email input.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-search textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-search input.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-tel textarea.x-form-invalid-field, .x-form-type-tel input.x-form-invalid-field {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(images/grid/invalid_line.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    border-color: #c30;
}
```

I would try to override these styles. Replace the line with your personnalized image. Add in your custom stylesheet something like:

```
.x-form-type-text input.x-form-invalid-field {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
    background-image: url(cross.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```